# How to use relative url in Laravel 5 forms?

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my view, I have

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'/foo/bar']) !!}
```

This generates the following html

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/foo/bar" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input name="_token" value="5GnCAyo2v076FfvnF51jWbiddCdLX138TMxQl83c" type="hidden">
</form>
```

The generated action is an absolute URL. How can I use `Form::open()` to create a relative URL?
I do not want `action="http://localhost/foo/bar"`, instead I want `action="/foo/bar"`.

Answer (score 0):

Need a little change in your code:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'foo/bar']) !!}
```

try with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=> url('foo/bar')]) !!}
```

you'll get http://site-url/foo/bar

or

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=> 'foo/bar']) !!}
```

but you'll get http://site-url/your/current/url/foo/bar

Comment: I tried this,  but when I submit I am losing the current directory. I have ,http://site-url/en/ and after submit goes to http://site-url/foo/bar